# Key for Chris Johnston's Subversion VS Code Extension?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am using this VS Code extension and I cannot make out what these icons are or mean.  Anyone know of a key out there?

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=johnstoncode.svn-scm

[image]

Comment: Wait... are those funny icons for each Author?  Like balloon people?

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/JohnstonCode/svn-scm/issues/754

Interesting. It is a setting for Gravatar use in VS Code; in the extension.